# Dispose jqTree object completely

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqtree

I need to reload data depending on a query result, but after I pass all the information to the treeview object again, the parent node is lost. I have tried to reset the json object and it doesn't work. I tried to reload the partial view and it doesn't work. I really don't know what to do.

Also the events are not working properly. How I can reinitialize the jqTree?

i'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 btw.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove a jqtree using the **destroy** function:

```
$('#tree1').tree('destroy');
```